# PHPmailer content from a php file

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have Mail templates with Variables that I want to display in the email.
I add the E-Mail to the Mailer with:

```
$mail->Body = file_get_contents(INCLUDE_PATH."lib/mails/password_revover.php");
```

but I cant output `date('Y');` in the email, how I can solve this?

Comment: `f_g_c` slurps in the contents of a file verbatim. It does **NOT** execute any code within it. You want `include()` or `require()` instead, which slurp AND execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the template files so they can be loaded with `include`. For instance, make it define a function that returns the message body:

```
function mail_body() {
    ...
    return $message;
}
```

and then do:

```
include("lib/mail/password_recover.php");
$mail->Body = mail_body();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're file isn't being parsed. Instead do this via output buffering:

```
ob_start();
include INCLUDE_PATH."lib/mails/password_revover.php";
$mail->Body = ob_get_clean();
```

The first line starts output buffering, catching anything that gets echoed from there on. `ob_get_clean` returns the buffered data in a string and clears the buffer, ensuring it doesn't enter the regular output stream.